# Самопроизвольное переопределение переменных

Tags: php

Доброго всем утра!
Не представляю как вообще такое возможно, но тем не менее проблема такая есть. И судя по ответам гугла только лишь у меня одного.
Есть некий сайт, ядро 1C-Bitrix 9.1.1. Версия PHP, с недавних пор, 5.3.

Последнее время (Еще до перехода на 5.3) сталкиваюсь с поистине волшебной ошибкой, например:

```
<?php
Class MYCLASS
{
   ******
   public function get_element_by_id($TYPE, $ELEMENT_ID)
   {
        $result = array();
        ****
        $result['ID'] = 59; // Присваиваю переменной значение, например, 59
        ****
        return $result; // В конце функции, возвращаю переменную
   }
   ******
}
$MYCLASS = new MYCLASS();
$element = $MYCLASS->get_element_by_id('SERVICES', 59);
?>
```

Вроде бы все просто и логично, значение $element['ID'] должно быть равно именно 59 и никак иначе. Но не тут-то было, там вообще может оказаться любое число, или еще что угодно!

Ну думаю, наверно где-то ошибся, с кем не бывает. Но ошибки в упор не вижу, пробую так:

```
<?php
Class MYCLASS
{
   ******
   public function get_element_by_id($SERVICES, $ELEMENT_ID)
   {
        $result = array();
        ****
        $result['ID'] = 59; // Присваиваю переменной значение 59
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
        return $result; // Прямо в !следующей за print_r строке возвращаю переменную
   }
   ******
}
$MYCLASS = new MYCLASS();
$element = $MYCLASS->get_element_by_id('SERVICES', 59);
?>
```

Как результат в браузере вижу

```
Array
(
   ******
   [ID] => 59
   ******
)
```

А в $element['ID'] опять абсолютно произвольная, извиняюсь, хрень.
Поскольку сроки горели, клиенту нужен рабочий сайт а не мои оправдания, разборки отложил до лучших времен и сделал так:

```
<?php
Class MYCLASS
{
   ******
   public function get_element_by_id($SERVICES, $ELEMENT_ID)
   {
        $result = array();
        ****
        $result['ID'] = 59; // Присваиваю переменной значение 59
        $result['ELEMENT_ID'] = 59; // Дублирую значение переменной $result['ID']
        return $result; // Прямо в !следующей строке возвращаю переменную
   }
   ******
}
$MYCLASS = new MYCLASS();
$element = $MYCLASS->get_element_by_id('SERVICES', 59);
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($element); // Проверяю что получилось
?>
```

В браузере вижу

```
Array
(
   ******
   [ID] => Абсолютно произвольное значение
   [ELEMENT_ID] => 59
   ******
)
```

Так до сих пор на этой заплатке все и держится
Дальше больше, если кто не в курсе, в битриксе класс CDATABASE в ответ на запрос Query возвращает ссылку на объект у которого среди прочих есть метод Fetch для перебора результатов. 
Пишу следующий код:

```
<?php
$res = $DB->Query("SELECT `field_1`, `field_2` FROM `table`");
while($row = $res->Fetch())
{
    // Тут что-то делаю с результатами
}
?>
```

Запускаю скрипт, и вижу ошибку:
Fatal error: Call to a member function Fetch() on a non-object in ********** on line**

Удивляюсь как такое возможно и для проверки дописываю пару строк

```
<?php
$res = $DB->Query("SELECT `field_1`, `field_2` FROM `table`");
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_class_methods($res));
while($row = $res->Fetch())
{
    // Тут что-то делаю с результатами
}
?>
```

В браузере вижу

```
Array
(
    ***********
    [1] => Fetch
    ***********
)
```

И ниже все то-же сообщение что мой $res НЕ является обьектом
Провозился почти всю ночь, и уже от безнадеги тупо переименовал $res в $res1 АЛИЛУЯ она заработала!!!!

Честно говоря, грешил на битрикс, мало того что он сам по себе имеет крайне запутанную архитектуру и порой выдает труднопредсказуемые результаты, так еще до моего прихода, код много раз дописывался и переписывался различными программистами и не очень. Но сегодня пришел к выводу что всетаки битрикс тут не при делах.

Задачка на уровне детского сада, создать два подключения к разным БД, получить из первой доступы к почтовым ящикам собрать все письма и сохранить их во вторую БД

Пишу, примерно такой код

```
<?php
// Тут вообще НЕ подключаю файлы битрикса, все своими силами
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysql.php';// Подключаю самописный класс которым пользуюсь постоянно уже не первый год
$DBBITRIX = new MYSQL(
                  array(
                      'name' => 'DB_BITRIX', 
                      'pass' => 'PASSWORD', 
                      'user' => 'USER', 
                      'host' => 'localhost', 
                      'show_error' => true
                      )
                     );
$DBMAIL   = new MYSQL(
                  array(
                      'name' => 'DB_MAIL', 
                      'pass' => 'PASSWORD', 
                      'user' => 'USER', 
                      'host' => 'localhost', 
                      'show_error' => true
                      )
                     );

$DBMAIL->query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
while($row = $DBMAIL->get_row())
{
    /// Тут собираю результаты
}
$DBMAIL->free();

$DBBITRIX->query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
while($row = $DBBITRIX->get_row())
{
     ********
     $DBMAIL->query("INSERT INTO `table` SET `field_1`='тут что-то из письма' *******");
     ********
}
$DBBITRIX->free();
?>
```

Запускаю и вижу ошибку MySQL в которой говорится что запрос "INSERT INTO `table` SET `field_1`='тут что-то из письма' *******" Выполнить невозможно поскольку в базе DB_BITRIX нет таблицы из базы DB_MAIL тоесть вроде как получается что $DBMAIL непонятным образом начала ссылаться на тот-же экземпляр класса что и $DBBITRIX При этом никаких переназначений я опять-же не делаю, я же себе не враг.

Это меня добило окончательно, уже не знаю, что и думать. Толи это какая-то волшебная ошибка PHP толи это я волшебный идиот!?

К сожалению, никакие исходники показывать не имею права, но все приведенные выше куски кода, максимально приближены к реальным. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, хоть в чем может быть проблема? Куда копать? 
Уже весь мозг сломал, даже предположить не могу в чем причина....

Comment: Битрикс-гадость.

Постоянные ошибки и неудобное форматирование всего.

Comment: Не понял, зачем в битриксе делать прямые запросы к базе? Там же мощный АПИ есть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если код настолько запутан, что "стандартные" средства отладки не помогают и вся работа кода кажется мистикой, значит уже давно пора переходить на полноценные средства для отладки кода.

Пошаговая отладка, анализ stack trace'а, наблюдение за переменными, профилирование и т.п. - в PHP это все можно делать при помощи [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote) и практически любого популярного IDE ([PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/index.html#Visual_PHP_Debugger), [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html), [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf), [Komodo](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/debugphp.html), etc)

Поверьте, лучше один раз потратить какое-то время на изучение всех этих механизмов отладки и потом всегда иметь четкое представление как работает ваш код, чем гадать на кофейной гуще каждый раз, как перепутаете где-нибудь оператор.

Comment: В том то и дело что явно ничего не перепутал, по крайней мере во втором случае точно!
Ну скажите, что можно напутать в двух строках?
$res = $DB->Query("ЗАПРОС К БД");
while($row = $res->Fetch());
А ведь $res куда-то девается...
Бррр. В общем бред какой то...

Хотя отладкой конечно, уже давно пора занятся, одного только "мервого" кода почти каждый день по сотне строк выгребаю.

Comment: > Ну скажите, что можно напутать в двух строках? $res = $DB->Query("ЗАПРОС К БД"); while($row = $res->Fetch());

Лукавите :) Где-же тут две строчки, когда здесь идет вызов методов стороннего класса, в которых может быть все что угодно наворочено. 
Сделайте стек трейс, уверен между этими двумя строчками обнаружится еще не одна сотня вызовов различных функций :)

Comment: Ну пожалуй, наверно вы правы. Пойду рыть дальше %-/

UPD: Извиняюсь, совсем торможу. Спасибо!